# Is there an efficient way to change all the elements in a list such that the lowest number becomes a zero, and each number after has integer spacing?

Tags: python, list, integer

I want to achieve the following in general, and ideally without using a for loop to just step through each element since that seems inefficient. Every element of the list is going to be int type.

3 Examples:

```
In  [1]: L1 = [3,6,19,6,3,3,19]
In  [2]: f(L1)
Out [2]: [0,1,2,1,0,0,2]

In  [3]: L2 = [0,1,2,4,1,4,1,0]
In  [4]: f(L2)
Out [4]: [0,1,2,3,1,3,1,0]

In  [5]: L3 = [2,3,3,4,2,2,3,4]
In  [6]: f(L3)
Out [6]: [0,1,1,2,0,0,1,2]
```

The order of the numbers doesn't matter, but the relative frequency is important.

My current attempt works if there's no spacing between numbers - like in L3.

My attempt:

```
def f(L):
    L = np.array(L) - min(L)
    return list(L)
```

but this obviously doesn't handle differences the way I want it to. If I could avoid a for loop for each element of L and also avoid doing element wise comparison (like checking if the next lowest number after 19 is 6 in L1) that'd be ideal, but it's not obvious to me there's a way to avoid that.

Comment: Your output seems to be replacing each number with the index of the first occurrence of the number?

Comment: I think the intent is that the number is replaced according to its rank in the original data. The smallest value becomes 0 each time it appears, next smallest becomes 1 etc.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel is exactly right. That is what I'm trying to do. I'm implementing the first suggestion right now and will mark it as an accepted answer if it does what I'm looking for. Otherwise I'll edit my question to provide more/better context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can possibly do this in better than O(n) time, so trying to avoid a `for` loop over the list isn't useful.  Here's the approach I'd take:

```
>>> def f(nums):
...     m = {num: i for i, num in enumerate(sorted(set(nums)))}
...     return [m[num] for num in nums]
...
>>> f([3,6,19,6,3,3,19])
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2]
>>> f([0,1,2,4,1,4,1,0])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 0]
>>> f([2,3,4,4,2,2,3,4])
[0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Note that the sort is O(m log m), where *m* is the number of unique numbers, so in the worst case this is O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

Note, if you are actually using `numpy` to begin with, you can use `numpy.unique` with the `return_inverse=True` arguments for this particular factorization:

```
>>> np.unique(L1, return_inverse=True)
(array([ 3,  6, 19]), array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2]))
```

Which should be very performant, but you should profile for your particular use-case. Note, this has the behavior you want because `np.unique` will return the *sorted* unique elements of the array.

Comment: The first method appears to be incorrect in general, implicitly assuming that the first time an int `i` is seen, nothing larger than `i` was seen before it. For example, apply it to `[3, 2, 1, 0]` and the result is `[0, 1, 2, 3]`  That contradicts the requirement "the lowest number becomes a zero". I assume the same is true of the 2nd method, but didn't check it.

Comment: @TimPeters "the lowest number becomes a zero" Ah, didn't notice that requirement. OK, removed the first approach. The second actually doesn't work this way. I didn't read carefully enough and was confused by "the order doesn't matter"

Comment: Your solution is the one I'm going with since I am using numpy, but I'm going to mark the other question correct because I didn't explicitly say I was using numpy so I think it answers the question I posed better.  But I'd appreciate if someone let me know if this is the incorrect etiquette on stack overflow.